Static TLS block fir library loading in .NET
Is there possible to change size of static TLS block in .NET project?
The issue with loading big size libcef.so (1.4 Gb) on CSharp project side. I've got exception like "Can't allocate memory on static TLS block". I tried to use LD_PRELOAD, but has no effect. Changing of variable glibc.rtld.optional_static_tls and add compile options -ftls-model=global-dynamic, -fPIC in CMake has no effect too. On Windows 10 x64 the project is working fine. If i trying to load libcef.so from C++ project on Linux is working too.
enter image description here

"exception like" "tried to use LD_PRELOAD". What was the verbatim text of the exception? What library did you try to preload? Please be as specific as you can. Note for others: TLS = thread-local storage.

You can try the debugging approach in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1722181 to collect what library tried to eat how much TLS and so how much you need.

glibc.rtld.optional_static_tls seems like it could help. How did you change it and what did you change it to?

Thanks for answer! The full text of exception is: @cannot allocate memory in static TLS block libcef.so". By LD_PRELOAD: firstly i tried to add environment: export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/library/libcef.so. It's not helped and secondary i tried LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/library/libcef.so /path/to/executefile/ and i had segmentation fault.

for change optional_static_tls i use: export GLIBC_TUNABLES=glibc.rtld.optional_static_tls=2048
